# Set up an EC2 Server to run as Proxy usable through Ruby

Tags: ruby, proxy, amazon-ec2, mechanize

I need to access a site from behind a proxy server.  I can do it from within a EC2 instance, but it would be really nice if I could use my own EC2 server and when using nokogiri or mechanize to be able to set the instance as my proxy.  I have tried enabling HTTP requests and SSH requesting from any source.  When I try to connect to the server through ruby running this code.

```
open('http://example.com/', :proxy => 'http://ec2-54-242-232-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80')
```

I get back either...  A connection error(2)
Or an error saying that the end of the file has been reached. 
I have tried basic authentification with valid credentials as well.
Can someone try and walk me through the process of setting up an ec2 server and using it as a proxy server through mechanize?

Comment: You would need to run a http proxy on that instance and open your security groups to allow you to connect, but what you want won't work anyway because yelp blocks EC2 traffic. So does a lot of other sites (stackoverflow for example)

Comment: Okay, how can I go about it anyway.  How do I "run a http proxy" on my instance.

Comment: That's not a programming question, and it wouldn't work anyway like I said.

Comment: Oh, okay then.  Thanks for trying to help anyway, is there a link you could direct me to that may have an answer, or possibly answer it hear, or is that not possible.  Again, thanks for trying got help.

Comment: Just google for 'ec2 http proxy'

Comment: Okay, most of them involve setting up the server via localhost, and connecting through your browser, which you said was impossible in a previous post.  Is there something else you could possibly supply me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you need to do a few things:

1. Make sure your EC2 instance is running some sort of proxy server (Squid is good)
2. Make sure your instance and Squid (or whatever) are set to accept external connections
3. Configure your Ruby script appropriately

To setup the EC2 instance, use this guide: http://hackingonstuff.net/post/23929749838/setting-up-a-squid-proxy-on-aws

To setup the script just make sure it uses the instance's public DNS name and the port your proxy service is listening on.  The public DNS name/ip changes each time you launch the instance so just be sure not to over look that small but important detail. :)